# Python selenium wont send all of my keys to the input field

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am using send_keys to send strings to input fields. The problem is when I am trying to send the characters : ")" and "&" it will not send those, it just ignores the characters. This is only a problem on one page, on several other pages I can send these characters. I am also able to input this characters manually in the browser, so it has to be something with my script. Any suggestions?

I`m using selenium 2.47.1 with firefox driver

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="labelExpensesetPurposeArrangement"]')).clear()
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="labelExpensesetPurposeArrangement"]')).send_keys("(&")
```

The code is just an example. I just clear the input field and enter the value.

Comment: Have you tried with different firefox versions? Is it reproducible in Chrome?

Comment: How about a code sample of where you sendkeys?

Comment: Not yet, added a code sample.